# Обособление пояснения с ИЗ-ЗА в предложении

Tags: уточнения

Имеется предложение:
*В них(,) из-за большого количества людей, машин, поездов, трамваев(,) шум не стихает даже ночью*

Правильно понимаю, что уточнением данная конструкция не является, а значит, выделять её не нужно?

Answer (score 2):

В данном предложении обстоятельственный оборот **со значением причины** нужно выделить обязательно:

***В них, из-за большого количества людей, машин, поездов, трамваев, шум не стихает даже ночью.***

Обычно обособление обстоятельств на основе предложных форм существительного является факультативным, но здесь оборот  обособляется вследствие большой **распространенности** и **собственных знаков препинания**.

Оборот не имеет значения уточнения, но это не имеет отношения к решению этой задачи.

Правило Розенталя http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=112#pp112
Обстоятельства, выраженные существительными.